# Toolbar findViewById return null pointer

Tags: java, android

I've already read links about this problem.
Main solutions were:

- disable default action bar. I did....
- put findViewById after setContent. I did...
- include the layout in the main activity layout.xml file. I did..

but still getting null pointer back. I'm getting crazy because also I can't see the toolbar in the preview.

**styles.xml**

No action bar set.

```
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

**my_toolbar.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DarkActionBar">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

**activity_maps.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        layout="@layout/my_toolbar"/>


    <!-- Add Google Maps Fragment to the MainActivity -->
    <fragment xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/my_toolbar"
        tools:context=".MapsActivity" />
        <!--android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"-->



    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btClear"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/send_screenshot" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

**MapsActivity.java**

....

```
@Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
            // Get fused location client
            mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
            Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
            myToolbar.setTitle("my title");
            setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
            // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
            SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        }
```

....

Comment: I think is because they have the same `id` `@+id/my_toolbar`. try to change one them

Comment: I don't think so defining id two places may cause this issue. @Maicake can you please share the full log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<include android:id="@+id/my_toolbar" layout="@layout/my_toolbar"/>`

Remove the id field here, it's defined again in the my_toolbar layout.

Answer (score 1):

In your activity_maps.xml 
instead of writing this

```
 <include
    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
    layout="@layout/my_toolbar"/>
```

Write this

```
<include
    layout="@layout/my_toolbar"/>
```

or provide any other id but not this one in your include tag

```
android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
```

Answer (score 1):

Extract layout as a view in your `MapsActivity` and then form that view get toolbar like this.

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Get fused location client
        mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

        //get that view of <include> tag
        //I suggest change the name to something else, same name for include and toolbar will be difficult to understand and read.
        View includeLayout = findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar) //id of include

        //from that includeToolbar you can get toolbar with the Id.            
        Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) includeLayout.findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
        myToolbar.setTitle("my title");


        setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }
```